# Pass value from PHP to JS with Smarty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

How to pass a value from php to javascript? I'm working with smarty and i tried this but js seems to take it as a a string. The value is set to 20.

```
$smarty->assign('settings', $settings); //$settings is an array
```

$settings is coming from an file, basically it are some settings.
i want to select an option in an html doc with that value but it is not working.

```
<select id="entrys">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
</select>
```

and in the js file then:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#entrys').val("{$settings['frontendEntrys']}");
});
```

But no option is selected then not even the first or default value and if i try to print {$settings['frontendEntrys']} it's also not working. It just seems to be taken as a string.

BTW: Is it a good way to pass some settings with smarty or generally? How can i pass the values if i don't use smarty? Would this be correct? Is this a good way, if it's done in an html file?

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo $settings['entrys']; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: I would do `var data = <?=json_encode($settings['entrys'])?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In smarty you can use: `{$myarray|@json_encode}`
[Howto generate json with smarty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285514/howto-generate-json-with-smarty)

So it would be probably something like this:

```
<script>
    var data = {$settings|@json_encode}
</script>
```

Then you can access that in js like normal object `data.entrys;` less php/js mishmash more clear js code.

`$('#entrys').val(data.entrys);`

Answer (score 1):

Define a global JS variable on your Smarty template file :

```
<script>
_Entrys = {$settings['frontendEntrys']};
</script>
```

And use on JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#entrys').val(_Entrys);
});
```

Comment: Correct, but this will only work if `$settings['frontendEntrys']` is number. In all other cases (string, array, object) you will get errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach, which has the added advantage of synchronizing the HTML and .ini settings.

```
<select id="entrys">
{foreach $settings as $setting}
    <option {if $setting == 'frontendEntrys'}selected{/if}>{$setting}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```