# Creating a URL encoded string in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to create a string of values taken from variables in the backend with the following structure:

> Before encoding:

```
transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va lue=25.20;item_quantity=1; 
transaction_id=0815/2009;transaction_cid=54AB;item_id=402163045080;item_va lue=25.20;item_quantity=1;
```

> After encoding:

```
transaction_id%3D0815%2F2009%3Btransaction_cid%3D54AB%3Bitem_id%3D40216304 5080%3Bitem_value%3D25.20%3Bitem_quantity%3D1%3Bitem_id%3D847163029054%3Bi tem_value%3D16.81%3Bitem_quantity%3D2
```

I have managed to create an array with the necessary data in this form:

```
'[{"transaction_id":"233684","transaction_cid":"d2871c13c507583048d8ecf4a16f94c0","i tem_id":"3524","item_value":"4915.13","item_quantity":"1"}]',
```

But what I need is all these elements of the array in a url encoded string.

I am out of ideas since all that I try seems to not work.

Using JSON.stringify keeps the `":"` and the `"""`, using alert() or join also keeps the `":"` and is not performant.

Example array:

> arr : {key1: 'a', key2:'b', key3:'c'}

non encoded result:

> str : 'key1=a;key2=b;key3=c'

desired result:

> str : 'key1%3Da%3Bkey2%3Db%3Bkey3%3Dc'

Here is my code so far:

```
[{foreach from=$orderArticles item="currOrderArticle"}]
        [{assign var="currBasePrice2" value=$currOrderArticle->getBasePrice()}]

    products_info.push(
              {
              transaction_id: '[{$order->oxorder__oxordernr->value}]', 
              transaction_cid: '[{$order->oxorder__oxuserid->value}]', 
              item_id: '[{$currOrderArticle->oxorderarticles__oxartnum->value}]',
              item_value: '[{$basket->getDiscountedNettoPrice()}]',
              item_quantity: '[{$currOrderArticle->oxorderarticles__oxamount->value}]'
              });

    [{/foreach}]
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Is http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl helpful?

Comment: es this works for the URL encoding, but I still need to find a way to get to that string.

Comment: Combine with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285514/howto-generate-json-with-smarty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine json_encode (or serialize if you only need to use it in php) and escape:

```
{$arr|json_encode|escape:'url'}
```

Also, if you want to make the string shorter you can use compression:

```
{$arr|json_encode|gzcompress|base64_encode|escape:'html'}
```

Though that may be a bit overkill for short arrays and you'll have to base64_decode, gzuncompress and json_decode the string when you receive it.

Comment: Hey Borgtex, thanks for your answer. Could you please detail me a bit on how the syntax should be knowing that I'm using smarty? Should I simply assign result : {$arr|json_encode|escape:'url'}? I'm using perhaps a wrong syntax and it is breaking my code

Comment: Don't know what smarty version are you using. You also seem to be using custom delimiters ('[{' instead of '{'). So, in smarty 3, if you want to assign it to a variable it would be [{$variable_name=$array_name|json_encode|escape:'url'}]

Comment: I think its a different version, the way I do the assignation is a simple "var : array" in the .push statement, but im not sure how to specify the treatment of the array to encode it and so on.

Comment: Ummmm I'm not sure what you're trying to do... the push statement is javascript, the code within [{ }] is Smarty, smarty is processed in the server and javascript in the browser. As for your question I supposed you wanted something like www.mypage.com/mycode.php?variable=encoded_array

Comment: No, I want to get the values from the backend in the form of an array, and then transform it into an encoded string and pass it into the datalayer